# Install django on webfaction

Tags: django, webfaction, syncdb

I am trying to install django on Webfaction, and i have one all the steps like in the tutorial here: http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Installing+OSQA+on+WebFaction

But when i am trying to synchronyse the database, if i enter python2.5 manage.py syncdb --all i get: Usage: manage.py syncdb [options]

Create the database tables for all apps in INSTALLED_APPS whose tables haven't already been created.

manage.py: error: no such option: --all

if i enter manage.py syncdb i get Error: Could not import settings 'osqa.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings

i have set all like in the tutorial...is a problem with the import line in settings.py : from settings_local import * as if i comment that i get an error from if DEBUG line... Where am i wrong??? all the files have the same rights - 617 and i cannot change the rights, also i don;t think is a problem with rights. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling DEBUG in the settings file to see if you get any further indication of the failure. There is a path problem somewhere. You could also try running python in the osqa directory and enter import settings_local to see what you get.